# How to extract #tags from string?

Tags: php

I would like to extract all #words from a string, for example if I have this string:

```
Hello #people how are you doing #today I am in #asia and weather is super #nice
```

I need a PHP function that will return me these:

```
#people
#today
#asia
#nice
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where I apply your request

```
$string = "Hello #people how are you doing #today I am in #asia and weather is super #nice";
$regex = '~(#\w+)~';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
   foreach ($matches[1] as $word) {
      echo $word .'<br/>';
   }
}
```

Comment: I ran this and it doesn't display anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, a character was missing.